# Loop Assembly Input and print A to Z. Irvine

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I have write a program which will input a number from 2 - 26 and will print A - Z. for example, if I input 3 then the output will be

```
AAA
AAA
AAA
```

So far I have written this much

```
    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc 
    ;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 
    .data

         heading            BYTE "CSE 2120 - Assignment # 8 - Manan Davda", 0
         msg1           BYTE "Enter a row count (from 2 to 26): ", 0
         input          SDWORD 0
         index          BYTE 65,0
    ;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    ;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
.code
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|                                                               
main PROC   
     mov edx, OFFSET heading    
     call WriteString                       ;Print The Heading (CSE2120 .....)
     call Crlf                          ;Blank Line
     call Crlf                          ;New Line
     mov ebx, OFFSET input                  ;initialize Large number
     mov edi, 0
;Read Data ( Integers )
    mov edx, OFFSET msg1
    call WriteString                        ;Print a statement asking users to input Number 
    call ReadInt                            ;Get keyboard input from user
;   mov esi, eax                        ;Storing array
;   mov ecx, input
    mov edi, eax
    mov esi, eax
    call Crlf                               ;New Line

L1:
L2:
    mov al, index
    call writeChar
    cmp esi, 1
    jng L2_END
    dec esi
    jmp L2
    L2_END:

    call Crlf
    add index,1
    cmp edi, 1
    jng L1_END
    dec edi
    mov esi, 0
    jmp L1
L1_END:
call Crlf
exit
main ENDP 
END main
```

What should I do in the second loop so that I can get output when input is 3 as

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

instead of

```
AAA
B
C
```

it is not looping.

Below is the irvine file:

```
; Include file for Irvine32.lib             (Irvine32.inc)

;OPTION CASEMAP:NONE        ; optional: make identifiers case-sensitive

INCLUDE SmallWin.inc        ; MS-Windows prototypes, structures, and constants
INCLUDE VirtualKeys.inc

.NOLIST
; Last update: 7/29/05

;----------------------------------------
; Procedure Prototypes
;----------------------------------------
CloseFile PROTO     ; close a file handle
Clrscr PROTO        ; clear the screen
CreateOutputFile PROTO      ; create file for writing
Crlf PROTO      ; output carriage-return / linefeed
Delay PROTO     ; delay for n milliseconds
DumpMem PROTO       ; display memory dump
DumpRegs PROTO      ; display register dump
GetCommandTail PROTO        ; get command-line string
GetDateTime PROTO,      ; get system date and time
  startTime:PTR QWORD
GetMaxXY PROTO      ; get console rows and columns
GetMseconds PROTO       ; get milliseconds past midnight
GetTextColor PROTO      ; Get the console window's color attributes. 
Gotoxy PROTO        ; set the cursor position
IsDigit PROTO       ; return ZF=1 if AL is a decimal digit
MsgBox PROTO        ; display popup message box
MsgBoxAsk PROTO     ; display popup yes/no question box
OpenInputFile PROTO     ; open file in input mode
ParseDecimal32 PROTO        ; convert unsigned decimal string to 32-bit binary
ParseInteger32 PROTO        ; convert signed decimal string to 32-bit binary
Randomize PROTO     ; reseed random number generator
RandomRange PROTO       ; generate random integer in specified range
Random32 PROTO      ; generate 32-bit random integer
ReadInt PROTO       ; read signed decimal integer from console
ReadChar PROTO      ; reach single character from console
ReadDec PROTO       ; read unsigned decimal integer from console
ReadFloat PROTO     ; read floating-point value from keyboard
ReadFromFile PROTO          ; read buffer from input file
ReadHex PROTO       ; read hexadecimal integer from console
ReadKey PROTO       ; Reads keyboard input if available (4/6/03)
ReadKeyFlush PROTO      ; Flush ReadKey buffer and repeat counter (4/6/03)
ReadString PROTO        ; read string from console
SetTextColor PROTO      ; set console text color
ShowFPUStack PROTO      ; write floating-point stack to console window
StrLength PROTO     ; returns the length of a string
WaitMsg PROTO       ; display wait message, wait for Enter key
WriteBin PROTO      ; write integer to output in binary format
WriteBinB PROTO     ; write binary integer in byte, word,or doubleword format
WriteChar PROTO     ; write single character to output
WriteDec PROTO      ; write unsigned decimal integer to output
WriteFloat PROTO        ; write ST(0) to console in floating-point format
WriteHex PROTO      ; write hexadecimal integer to output
WriteHexB PROTO     ; write hexadecimal integer in word or doubleword format
WriteInt PROTO      ; write signed integer to output
;WriteStackFrame        ; write stack frame data (James Brink--see proto later in this file)
;WriteStackFrameName        ; write stack frame data with proc name (James Brink)
WriteString PROTO       ; write null-terminated string to output
WriteToFile PROTO       ; write a buffer to an output file
WriteWindowsMsg PROTO       ; write last error message generated by MS-Windows


; Copy a source string to a target string.
Str_copy PROTO,
    source:PTR BYTE,
    target:PTR BYTE

; Return the length of a null-terminated string..
Str_length PROTO,
    pString:PTR BYTE

; Compare string1 to string2. Set the Zero and
; Carry flags in the same way as the CMP instruction.
Str_compare PROTO,
    string1:PTR BYTE,
    string2:PTR BYTE

; Trim a given trailing character from a string.
; The second argument is the character to trim.
Str_trim PROTO,
    pString:PTR BYTE,
    char:BYTE

; Convert a null-terminated string to upper case.
Str_ucase PROTO,
    pString:PTR BYTE

;******** Procedures by James Brink ********************************
; Used by permission.

WriteStackFrameName PROTO,
           numParam:DWORD,     ; number of parameters passed to the procedure
           numLocalVal: DWORD, ; number of DWordLocal variables
           numSavedReg: DWORD, ; number of saved registers
           procName: PTR BYTE

WriteStackFrame PROTO,
           numParam:DWORD,     ; number of parameters passed to the procedure
           numLocalVal: DWORD, ; number of DWordLocal variables
           numSavedReg: DWORD  ; number of saved registers


;-----------------------------------
; Standard 4-bit color definitions
;-----------------------------------
black        = 0000b
blue         = 0001b
green        = 0010b
cyan         = 0011b
red          = 0100b
magenta      = 0101b
brown        = 0110b
lightGray    = 0111b
gray         = 1000b
lightBlue    = 1001b
lightGreen   = 1010b
lightCyan    = 1011b
lightRed     = 1100b
lightMagenta = 1101b
yellow       = 1110b
white        = 1111b

; This structure is returned by the FSTSW
; instruction in protected mode:

FPU_ENVIRON STRUCT
    controlWord    WORD ?
    ALIGN DWORD
    statusWord     WORD ?
    ALIGN DWORD
    tagWord        WORD ?
    ALIGN DWORD
    instrPointerOffset     DWORD ?
    instrPointerSelector   DWORD ?
    operandPointerOffset   DWORD ?
    operandPointerSelector WORD ?
    WORD ?  ; not used
FPU_ENVIRON ENDS

.LIST
```

Comment: `ReadInt` presumably returns a number in `eax`. You never get it into `edi`.

Comment: ok, will try and let you know

Comment: Hey @FrankKotler I have some more problem which i have update above can you look into it please? Thank You Soo much!

Comment: Ahh, sorry. Just before `L1_END` you `mov esi, 0`. Why zero? Put your number in `input` (or someplace) and reload `esi` with it there. I think that'll work. Could use `push` and `pop` also.